# How to return a Promise that maps over the result of a Promise in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, async-await, promise, opensearch

I have a method that makes a request that returns some JSON data.

```js
async borgs(): Promise<Borg[]> {
  const response = await fetch("api.example.com/borgs");
  return await response.json();
}
```

The thing is, the JSON has a complex structure, and the data contains irrelevant metadata fields, so I would like to map over the results to return an array of plain `Borg`, with the irrelevant fields discarded.

```js
async borgs(): Promise<Borg[]> {
  const response = await fetch("api.example.com/borgs");
  const json = await response.json();
  return json.data.borgs.map(borg => ({
    goodBorgField: borg.fields.goodBorgField,
  }));
}
```

I can't get this to work consistently. Sometimes I get

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError:
borg.fields is undefined
```

Why, and how can I fix this using async/await?

---

Response data example:

```json
{
  "data": {
    "borgs": [
      {
        "fields": {
          "goodBorgField": "value1",
          "_badBorgField": "value2"
        }
      },
      {
        "fields": {
          "goodBorgField": "value3",
          "_badBorgField": "value4"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Desired output: a Promise that resolves to:

```js
[
  {
    goodBorgField: "value1",
  },
  {
    goodBorgField: "value3",
  },
]
```

For completeness, type `Borg`:

```js
interface Borg {
  goodBorgField: string;
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "*If the Promise resolves before the mapping is executed*". The `response.json()` promise is `await`ed before calling `map`, it always has been fulfilled before the subsequent code runs.

Comment: Are you able to create a reproducible example on TS playground? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHsoHNkG8BQyyW66AJhtgGLAQA2ZAXMgM5hShYDc+AvvvlCRYiFJSwAlCCwAO6ECxQEiZOGDjNlRZACNMWFswDauAEQxaDFqebjeAXULJePfvjgsAniATIYAVx8wYHldfRYAJgAKAEpmAAUodABbYEUAHnEjewA+PCcEeTZkKGk5BRQAXmQ4AHc4YDA-CDAEAAso0zawMBlDAHp+5PQEAGtgADoQ-oA3AEZ+uAAGAGYEOAgANh0AWjgAdgRdgBYdTYidgE4dCIAOHeO7y9u4AFZXshgdHVMYniJCgomgArFjyWz6KSyIpVGr1RolMowiag+Sxf6IsD+KAgZCokATVTqCZ6bAsCbJOAyKKknCVPJRLREEjkcQ0ehMMLYCYWDnklkUfTshgAGicvBifz4AlpkViEzAbQgICiM2Q9OQgLBdAgEzo6CwqslXCAA

Comment: Are you sure that the response looks like your example in the cases where it fails? It certainly sounds like you sometimes get objects without a `.fields` property. Please `console.log(json)` and post the value that you see when getting an error.

Comment: "Not sure what you mean" yeah me neither, I thought I had a handle on it before this happened and made me question my understanding. I can't share the data. In my actual code I have the equivalent of if !response.ok return. Also, it is the same hardcoded OpenSearch request. I will work on reproducing this, and if I can't then I will close it. Thanks for the recommendations.

Comment: Sure enough, I looked in the Network tab at the responses I was getting and for some reason OpenSearch is periodically returning responses without `fields`... even though the request is hard-coded. Thank you @Bergi for pointing that out.. it's been a long day. Thank you @Lesiak for pointing out that such great sandbox and mocking tools exist. Next time, I will be sure to use them to save everyone's time.